# Second monitor renders black, except for mouse

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, mouse

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using the fglrx drivers for an AMD Radeon HD 7800 with 2 monitors. When I have the drivers installed the second monitor renders completely black except for the mouse pointer, I have no tool bar and any windows on that screen don't render. However everything still functions if I move my mouse to the correct places, such as power controls.

Also the catalyst screen identification watermarks render, but not the ubuntu display ones.